# the difference between a | b and a + b when a or b is zero

Tags: c

I am trying to implement an if statement in C using bit manipulation. the following code seems to work:

```
// if (x) then y else z
int conditional(int x, int y, int z) {
    int v = (!!x); //v is 1 or 0
    return ((v<<31)>>31)&y | ((~v<<31)>>31)&z;
}
```

however, when I replace "|" with "+" in the last line, the code fails when x = 0x80000000,y = 0x80000000,z = 0x7fffffff. It returns 0 instead of 0x80000000.

so my question is: why does the following fail? thanks!

```
((v<<31)>>31)&y + ((~v<<31)>>31)&z
```

edit:
I understand that | is bitwise OR and + is addition. but in this case, v is either 1 or zero, so (v<<31)>>31) is either all ones or all zeros. y | 0x00000000 should be the same as y + 0x00000000, right? specifically, v is 1. so the result with the above input should be y, but returns 0 when "+" is used.

Comment: ... they are two different operations. `|` is bitwise or, `+` is addition

Comment: 1+1 = 2, 1 |1 = 1. Get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid we have to use math.

The highest bits of your variables are set, thus doubling equals a bitshift of 1 left, which equals an overflow. All remaining bits are 0. Thus you get 0 as result.

Keep in mind that `|` is a bitwise `||` and does not carry over values to other binary digits. `+` does.

So speaking, if `a` and `b` are `orthogonal base` functions/vectors of your bitvectorspace (which in your case is not true) `a|b` and `a+b` are equal – but only then.

---

Update:

The root cause here is operator precedence: (decreasing order) `+` `&` `|`.

So

```
((v<<31)>>31)&y + ((~v<<31)>>31)&z
```

becomes

```
((v<<31)>>31) & (y + ((~v<<31)>>31)) & z
```

Comment: let a = ((v<<31)>>31), and b=((~v<<31)>>31), and one of a or b must be the zero vector. that's why i think a+b should also work.

Comment: But these are not the `a` and `b` of your question.

Comment: a and b are from the code posted above. it's implementing an if-else statement, so one of them is an all-zero mask, and the other is all-one.

Comment: Keep in mind that with a `+` you need to use additional brackets around the `a` and `b` which is the root cause of your findingsm, as the operator preference order is (decreasing order) `+` `&` `|`.

Answer (score 2):

In binary, 10+01 = 11 and 10 | 01 = 11. But 10 + 10 = 100, and 10 | 10 = 10.

Comment: Maybe also point out that 'difference between + and | in bit manipulation' is that + is not a bit manipulation but an additon

Comment: That is not the source of his problem.